# If $A$ is artinian and commutative, is $A[x]$ artinian?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

If $A$ is a commutative, artinian ring, is $A[x]$ artinian?

Comment: Was this a question question on an Algebra sheet, or how did you come across Artinian rings?

Comment: @DietrichBurde The result is true for Noetherian rings, so I wondered if it were also true for Artinian rings.

Comment: I see. You have a broad spectrum of interests, from algebra to martingale, random walks, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Polynomial rings are not Artinian, since $$(x)\supset(x^2)\supset(x^3)\supset\ldots$$

Answer (score 3):

A field $F$ is Artinian, but $F[x]$ is not Artinian because the descending chain
$$ (x)\supset (x^2)\supset (x^3)\supset\cdots $$
isn't stationary.